# Google Script return content type header missing error when making HTTP GET request

Tags: javascript

I try to make a GET request using Google Script. Sample code as below:

```
    var username = "test@test.com"; 
    var password = "12345"; 
    var headers = {
       "Authorization": "Basic "+ Utilities.base64Encode(username+":"+password)
         }; 
    var url = 'https://localhost/api/v2/get_sections/21';
    var options = {
                        'method': 'get',
                        'contentType' : 'application/json',
                        'headers': headers 
};
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

I received an error

> Request failed for https://localhost/api/v2/get_sections/21 returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"error":"Content-Type header missing (use Content-Type: application/json)"}

Is this the right way to make a get request?

Answer (score 1):

The `Content-Type` is also a header, try :

```
    var username = "test@test.com"; 
    var password = "12345"; 
    var headers = {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       "Authorization": "Basic "+ Utilities.base64Encode(username+":"+password)
         }; 
    var url = 'https://localhost/api/v2/get_sections/21';
    var options = {
        'method': 'get',
        'headers': headers 
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Comment: GET requests don't usually require a content/type, and your issue seems to be quite common (and unanswered on google threads). Can't you make your endpoint not require a content type?

Comment: Too bad It is a third party API which requires content type.